# Detect CLI or Wine executable in Manjaro

Tags: manjaro, wine, mono, binfmt

In my Linux Mint installation, I can directly execute a PE executable at the command line, and if it's a .NET/CLI executable, then it will automatically execute it with Mono, and otherwise, it will automatically execute it with Wine.

This works because [`binfmt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) is configured to run `/usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors` for both CLI and Wine executables.  This runs a series of detectors configured in `/var/lib/binfmts` to determine what type of PE executable it is and execute the appropriate command to run it.

In Manjaro, I have `binfmt`, but I don't have `run-detectors`.  So I guess the first match in `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` wins, and I guess since I installed Wine before I installed Mono, that's the one that wins.  That my supposition, anyway.  The symptom is that whenever I execute an `.exe` file from the command line, it runs Wine, even if it's a .NET executable.

I can't find a package that seems to supply this `run-detectors` utility.  Is there something like it in the standard or community repositories, or is there some other common way to set this up in the Arch world?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still hoping for a better answer from someone who knows a more idiomatic way to accomplish this, but in case there isn't one, for the benefit of future googlers, here's what I've done just to get it working for now:

From my Linux Mint installation, I copied `/usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli`.  This file is provided by the Ubuntu [mono-runtime](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/mono-runtime) package.  I don't like grabbing an executable from another distro, but it should be a fairly simple executable that doesn't rely on much that might differ between different distros, as long as they're the same platform.

Alternatively, the source code can be retrieved and built:

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --depth 1 --no-checkout git://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mono ubuntu-mono-binfmtdetect
cd ubuntu-mono-binfmtdetect
git sparse-checkout set debian/detector
git checkout
cd debian/detector
make
echo sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 ./binfmt-detector-cli /usr/local/bin/
```

`binfmt-detector-cli` is a simple command that tests whether a file is a CLI executable, returning `0` or `1` on exit to indicate yes or no.

My Manjaro installation doesn't have a `/usr/lib/cli` directory, so I copied this file straight to `/usr/bin/`.  Then a wrote a short shell script and saved it as `/usr/bin/binfmt-mono-wine`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if /usr/bin/binfmt-detector-cli "$1"; then
    mono "$@"
else
    wine "$@"
fi
```

Then I edited `/usr/lib/binfmt.d/mono.conf`, changing

```
:CLR:M::MZ::/usr/bin/mono:
```

to

```
:CLR:M::MZ::/usr/bin/binfmt-mono-wine:
```

and `/usr/lib/binfmt.d/wine.conf`, changing

```
:DOSWin:M::MZ::/usr/bin/wine:
```

to

```
:DOSWin:M::MZ::/usr/bin/binfmt-mono-wine:
```

You can see that both formats are now handled by the shell script, which uses the detector borrowed from Ubuntu to determine which command to launch.

Next, I had to deregister the old handlers and register the new ones.  I found out that systemd has a service that will do that:

```
sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-binfmt mono.conf
sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-binfmt wine.conf
```

The last thing to do is to register a pacman hook so that future upgrades to mono and wine don't overwrite my changes to their binfmt configurations.  I created `/etc/pacman.d/hooks/binfmt-mono-wine.hook` with these contents:

```
[Trigger]
Operation = Install
Operation = Upgrade
Type = File
Target = usr/lib/binfmt.d/mono.conf
Target = usr/lib/binfmt.d/wine.conf

[Action]
When = PostTransaction
Description = Updating binfmt configuration to use binfmt-mono-wine to differentiate between mono and wine executables
Exec = /usr/bin/xargs -I{} /usr/bin/sed -Ei 's_:/usr/bin/(mono|wine):_:/usr/bin/binfmt-mono-wine:_' /{}
NeedsTargets
```